# Joining tables to themselves and to eachother

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I've spent most of my day trying to figure this out so I guess it's time I ask the experts:
I'm trying to access my WordPress DB outside of WordPress, so I'm writing queries to get output from the somewhat complicated WordPress database.
There are several tables in the DB that use meta_values and meta_keys to store data about a post or user in multiple rows.
For Example here are four tables I need to pull from:

table: wp_postmeta

```
post_id  |    meta_key     |  meta_value
---------+-----------------+------------
2001     | _customer_user  | 3
2001     |order_description| smith
2001     | _order_total    | 300
```

table: wp_posts

```
ID  | post_type | post_status
----+-----------+------------
2001| shop_order| publish
```

table: wp_term_relationships

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id
----------+-----------------
 2001     |  190
```

table: wp_usermeta

```
user_id  | meta_key        |meta_value
---------+-----------------+----------
  3      | first_name      | Andy
  3      | last_name       | Mccormick
```

I've got this query to work great to display the Order Number (post_id) Customer ID, Order Description, and Order total in a single row:

```
 SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title,ot.meta_value as total,od.meta_value as order_desc, cu.meta_value as customer                
        FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS ot ON (wp_posts.ID = ot.post_id AND ot.meta_key='_order_total')
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS od ON (wp_posts.ID = od.post_id  AND od.meta_key='order_description')
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS cu ON (wp_posts.ID =cu.post_id  AND cu.meta_key='_customer_user')
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '190'
        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC"
```

However in another area I want to list the customers by name and not just by ID so I'm trying to get their first and last name from the wp_usermeta table like this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, cu.meta_value as customer, fn.meta_vale as fname, ln.meta_value as lname                
                FROM wp_posts
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS cu ON (wp_posts.ID = cu.post_id  AND cu.meta_key='_customer_user')
                LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS fn ON (cu.meta_key = fn.user_id AND fn.meta_key='first_name')
                LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS ln ON (cu.meta_key = ln.user_id AND ln.meta_key='last_name')
                LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
                AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '190'
                GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

I've also tried:
 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS fn ON ((cu.meta_key='_customer_user') = fn.user_id AND fn.meta_key='first_name')  along with a host of other subqueries and such.

Obviously I'm above my pay-grade in SQL queries right now so any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: What's the result you get from the second query?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'fn.meta_vale' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you might try this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, cu.meta_value as customer, fn.meta_vale as fname, ln.meta_value as lname                
                FROM wp_posts
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS cu ON (wp_posts.ID = cu.post_id  AND cu.meta_key='_customer_user')
                LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS fn ON (cu.meta_value = fn.user_id AND fn.meta_key='first_name') // Note meta_value instead of meta_key
                LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS ln ON (cu.meta_value = ln.user_id AND ln.meta_key='last_name') // Note meta_value instead of meta_key
                LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
                AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '190'
                GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

From what I've figured out, `cu.meta_value` is 3 in your example as it's the user's id, while `cu.meta_key` (as in your query) is '_customer_id', so you rather want to match `cu.meta_value` than `cu.meta_key`. Couldn't check though, as I have no WP installation laying around.

Comment: You are coorect but when I use:
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS fn ON (cu.meta_key = fn.user_id AND fn.meta_key='first_name')
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS ln ON (cu.meta_key = ln.user_id AND ln.meta_key='last_name')

I still get #1054 - Unknown column 'fn.meta_vale' in 'field list'

Comment: I guess you have a typo there (`fn.meta_vale` instead of `fn.meta_value`).

Comment: wow.. that was it. thanks!
maybe it wasn't above my pay-grade after all, just need more confidence.